# Using Roslyn (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) to query information of WebSite projects

Tags: c#, static-analysis, roslyn

I'm trying to implement a tool for static code analysis using Roslyn. The problem I'm finding is that when I load the solution, WebSite projects are not loaded into the Projects collection of the solution.

I've tried to convert those WebSite projects to WebApplication projects, then Roslyn was able to load the project, but when I look into the documents collection of the project, the documents (.cs files) of the App_Code folder are not there.

The ideal scenario for my case would be to be able to make the static code analysis on the WebSite files (including app_code files) without having to convert it.

Does anyone knows why Roslyn couldn't load WebSite projects, or the App_Code documents in the case of the WebApplication? Any suggestions?

Comment: Web Site "projects" are not projects. It seems you have found yet another reason to never use web site "projects", but instead to use web application projects.

Comment: John, I imagined that could be the reason, but searching in the web I found nothing to confirm that.

Comment: If you couldn't find anything, that's probably because web site "projects" are strange, and most people who know the difference don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files inside the App_Code folder was not being recognized by Roslyn because the build action was set to "Content" instead of "Compile". Changed the build action and the documents were loaded.

About WebSites not being loaded, looks like Roslyn needs the csproj file to understand the project. WebSites, as stated in comments, are not real projects and doesn't have that.